# Retrieving colour value from a x-y plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a R x-y plot.Can I retrieve the colour value of a point given its co-ordinates?
I generated the plot by this R code

```
plot(1:10,1:10,type="n",xlab="",ylab="") 
rect(par("usr")[1],par("usr")[3],par("usr")[2],par("usr")[4],col = "darkgreen")
```